Question about the limitations of regularization
I am training a neural network which is overfitting. Even when I increase the number of parameters, the test lost plateaus while the training loss keeps decreasing. Can regularization (like an L1 or L2 loss term) help me reach a lower test loss in this case, or would I be better off just augmenting my dataset? Is there anything obvious to try that I am missing?

Of course, regularization can help your validation loss decrease and it is very easy to add to a network (e.g. dropout).
